# How to set "google.com" NOT google chrome to dark mode

Tags: google-chrome

This is a very difficult question to google ironically because anything thing you search regarding dark mode gets overwhelmed by Google Chrome or support.google.com.

Both Google Chrome and support.google.com have a dark mode. However, I cannot find a way to turn the actual Google website dark, and I just refuse to believe that one does not exist.

It just doesn't seem possible that the google website wouldn't have a dark mode.

Comment: "I just refuse to believe that one does not exist." - what happens when a false belief is confronted by the truth? Do you want to know the truth? **Can you handle the truth?**  - because [_the truth_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hAAlDoAtV7Y) is that Google.com does not currently serve HTML+CSS to desktop browsers with any CSS with dark-mode colors specified. You can see this yourself with Google's own developer tools. So your belief is just flat-out wrong.

Comment: I wasn't being being completely serious when I said that. I was using a little exaggeration. Thought people would pick up on it.

Comment: @Dai But thank you, it just seems so odd why it wouldn't.

Comment: Google serves-up very different HTML+CSS to non-desktop browsers.

Comment: Ahhh, so is it possible on mobile? And laptops would fall into that desktop category I assume.

Comment: @Dai Wow, I'm not sure if it's a coincidence but my google page is black now! Think it is just cause of black history month though.

Comment: @Dai now Google is white again and I am confusion...

Comment: @Dai seems like google now has dark mode, got a prompt telling me dark mode had been activated! I doubt this post had anything to do with it, even with the timing matching up perfectly, but thank you Google!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search something on Google.
Then press the settings option under search box.

[image: Click on settings]

Click "Search Settings"
[image: Click on search settings]

Click on dark theme & press Save
[image: Click on Dark mode]